# Unable to locate an element which has only two attributes

Tags: selenium, testing, xpath, dynamic

[Screenshot of the requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQNBX.png)

I need to locate this element in my script, however i am unable to locate it with all the below possibilities.

1.//*[@class ='tabnavbar_subnav_level2_link' and contains(text(),'transactionHistory')]

2.//*[@class ='tabnavbar_subnav_level2_link' and ends-with(@href,'History.tpz')]

3.//*[@class ='tabnavbar_subnav_level2_link' and ends-with(. ,'History.tpz')]

4.//a[substring(@href, string-length(@href) - 3) = 'TransactionHistory.tpz']

As i try to run my script this takes me to the catch block.

Can anybody please help !

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) The html can be copied as well with right click -> copy as outerHTML. Very bad formated question

Comment: Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_

Comment: I am using Java as my language.

Answer (score 0):

To  locate the element with text as **Transaction history** you can use the following line of code :

- Python :

  ```
  myElem = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Transaction history")
  ```
- Java  :

  ```
  WebElement myElem = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Transaction history"));
  ```
- C# :

  ```
  IWebElement myElem = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Transaction history"));
  ```